# subtracting elements of a vector from each other in CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda

I have a vector (`x_dev`) in CUDA which has B elements and is of double type.
I am looking for the best way, to subtract each element from the next element, and overwrite the vector.
(I do not care about the last element).

Essentially, the corresponding of this c++ code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < B-1; i++)                           
    x_dev[i] = x_dev[i] - x_dev[i+1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`thrust::transform`](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__transformations.html#ga68a3ba7d332887f1332ca3bc04453792)

```
thrust::transform(x.begin(), x.end()-1, x.begin()+1, x.begin(), _1 - _2);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get this error
x_dev vector is defined as double in my code though! 

error: request for member ‘begin’ in ‘x_dev’, which is of non-class type ‘double*’
error: request for member ‘end’ in ‘x_dev’, which is of non-class type ‘double*’
error: request for member ‘begin’ in ‘x_dev’, which is of non-class type ‘double*’
error: request for member ‘begin’ in ‘x_dev’, which is of non-class type ‘double*’
error: ‘_1’ was not declared in this scope
error: ‘_2’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: You may want to read this. https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide

Comment: oh, I see what you are saying now.The thing is my vector is the output of a cuBlas function.So it seems first I need to create a device_vector  and copy the data into that, is that right?

Comment: Copying is not needed. You want to read all the document https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide#iterators-and-static-dispatching